# Ansible unable to run npm or rake command

Tags: ruby, npm, vagrant, bower, ansible

When setting up my VM, I'd like to have the playbook run DB migration as well as some npm commands. Here is the code snippet:

```
- name: Run DB Migration
   shell: rake db:migrate
   args:
     chdir: /opt/site
   sudo: no

- name: Install bower and grunt
  command: "npm install -g bower grunt-cli"
  args:
    chdir: /opt/site
  sudo: no

- name: Install bower packages
  command: "bower install"
  args:
    chdir: /opt/site
  sudo: no

- name: Install npm packages
  command: "npm install"
  args:
    chdir: /opt/site
  sudo: no
```

The error for npm stuff says:

```
TASK: [site | Install bower and grunt] ******************************
failed: [default] => {"cmd": "npm install -g bower grunt-cli", "failed": true, "item": "", "rc": 2}
msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The error for rake says:

```
TASK: [salemarked-api | Run DB Migration] *************************************
failed: [default] => {"changed": true, "cmd": " rake db:migrate ", "delta": "0:00:00.002664", "end": "2015-01-01 00:40:03.915189", "item": "", "rc": 127, "start": "2015-01-01 00:40:03.912525"}
stderr: /bin/bash: rake: command not found
```

I already tried adding `executable: /bin/bash` to the rake command but that didn't work either.

When I ssh into the VM, I was able to run those commands without any issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JacobBudin yeah, I have another playbook role that installs node and npm. As mentioned, I was able to run those commands successfully in the VM itself.

Comment: could you give the full path to run npm and rake command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `which rake` by hand and use the full path.  Roughly speaking, you don't have the `PATH` environment variable when it runs. Here's an example, though I'm assuming a certain path.

```
- name: Install bower and grunt
  command: "/usr/bin/npm install -g bower grunt-cli"
  args:
    chdir: /opt/site
  sudo: no
```

Also, `shell` and `command` usage is often an antipattern. In this case you'd be much better off using the [npm module](http://docs.ansible.com/npm_module.html) to replace two of the `command` calls. Also note you can remove `sudo: no`, that's implied.

Here's an improved example.

```
- name: install global node packages
  npm: name={{item}} path=/opt/site global=yes
  with_items:
    - bower
    - grunt-cli
```

Answer (score 4):

Hazarding a guess: The executables' paths are not in your `$PATH` because you're using the [`command`](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) Ansible module instead of the [`shell`](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html) module.

According to the documentation:

> The `shell` module takes the command name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments. It is almost exactly like the `command` module but runs the command through a shell (`/bin/sh`) on the remote node.

In the [ansible.command](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ansible.command) man page:

> As such, all paths to commands must be fully qualified.

So replace the commands with fully-qualified paths (or attempt to prefix them with `./`, seeing as you already have `chdir`) , or use `shell` instead (if they are in the user's `$PATH`).

Comment: If you look at the ```rake db:migrate``` command, I already use ```shell``` but that still didn't work.

Comment: @KoesBong `npm` is your primary inquiry, correct? These are two separate issues.

Comment: Both are my inquiries. I just tried using ```shell``` for npm and also same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
- name: Run my task
    shell: /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /your/path/here && RAILS_ENV={{api_rails_env}} bundle exec rake my_namespace:my_task'
```